# Jetty: Providing a message body always results in STATUS_EXCEPTED

Tags: java, http, jetty

We are using Jetty to send data from a server application to a client application also using Jetty.

For some reason when a the message content is set the response is always HttpExchange.STATUS_EXCEPTED. The message is being received on the other end however and everything seems intact.

This is the code for the server application where it is building and sending the request:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        try
        {
            client.start();

            ContentExchange exchange = new ContentExchange(true);
            //exchange.setMethod("POST");

            // Set the request URL
            logger.info("1");
            exchange.setURL("http://localhost:8180/network/");

            // Set the data contents type.
            logger.info("2");
            //exchange.setRequestContentType("application/zip");

            // Create a file input stream
            logger.info("3");
            FileInputStream inputFile = new FileInputStream(new File("ECF43d01.zip"));

            // Stream the file into the request
            logger.info("4");
            exchange.setRequestContentSource(inputFile); // <- This line makes the response always STATUS_EXCEPTED

            // Send the request
            logger.info("5");
            client.send(exchange);

            //logger.info(baseRequest.getMethod());

            // Waits until the exchange is terminated
            int exchangeState = exchange.waitForDone();

            if (exchangeState == HttpExchange.STATUS_COMPLETED)
                response.getWriter().println("Completed "+exchange.getResponseContent());
            else if (exchangeState == HttpExchange.STATUS_EXCEPTED)
                response.getWriter().println("Error with handler HttpExchange.STATUS_EXCEPTED");
            else if (exchangeState == HttpExchange.STATUS_EXPIRED)
                response.getWriter().println("Timeout");
```

This is the client receiving code:

```
public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest arg2, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException 
{
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AbstractHandler.class);

    logger.info("Starting");
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
    logger.info("Output");

    // We have handled the request. Send back a successful response
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    baseRequest.setHandled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just simply pipe the binary bytes from the ZIP file into the HTTP request. You might consider UUENCODing it and making sure the method is POST so it doesn't get tacked onto the end of the request URL. Here is a good example:

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/JavaClientExample.java

Comment: The packaging of data like this is handled ok from what I've done. The data comes out at the other end in the message body. Though I should probably add this into the problem description.